# How do I iterate through a class (Category) that has a subcategory list? i.e. List(Of Category)

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have:

```
Public Class Category

Public subCategories As List(Of Category)
Public products As List(Of Product)

End Class
```

and an instance of that class called allCategories. Each instance of Category inside of the list of subCategories may or may not have further subcategories, and may or may not have items, since the items could be nested away in further subcategories.

My question: How do I create a List(Of Product) that includes every item from every category throughout allCategories?

I could, of course, say

```
For Each category In allCategories
...
   For Each subCat In category
   ...
      For Each furtherSubCat In subCat
      ...
         For Each evenFurtherSubCat In furtherSubCat
```

But I'm guessing there's a better way, one that will truly iterate throughout the class.

Comment: You use recursion. Recursion is often one of the first things taught in programming classes but it is one of the least-used. It's a critical tool though, and should be used in situations where it's appropriate. Whenever the aim is to traverse a tree structure, recursion is your go-to option. An object with child objects that each has child objects and so on is inherently a tree structure. If you need more information on recursion, there is plenty around the web.

Comment: In short, you write a method that takes a `Category` object as input and returns a list of `Product` objects as output. Inside the method, you first create a list containing the `Product` items for the current `Category`, then you call the same method again for each child `Category` and add the output to the same list.  Finally, you return that list. No, I will not be writing the code for you.

Comment: There are various specific ways you could structure the code.  For instance, your method might return an array or generic `List` or you might just have one `List` at the class level that you add to directly in each method call or you might have one `List` that you pass into each method call as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion, right. Thank you, jmcilhinney.

Here's what I went with:

```
 Function GetAllProducts() As List(Of Product)

        Dim list As List(Of Product) = New List(Of Product)()

        For Each Product In Products
            list.Add(Product)
        Next

        For Each category In subCategories
            For Each Product In category.GetAllProducts()
                list.Add(Product)
            Next
        Next

        Return list

    End Function
```